# LDA/LSI Topic modelling in Gensim with predefined list of topics

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have a set of documents. I also have the title of topics based on which I want to categorize documents. My preference is to use LDA in Gensim. is there any way to feed my own list of topics in the topic modeling algorithm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the idea of LDA is to do topic modelling in unsupervised manner which means no predefined topics is needed to be fed to the model to predict topic(s) of a given document.